# React reposinveness + bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

React responsiveness
I just wanted to know how the responsiveness in to the react is possible ?

There are different ways to achieve responsive like

css-grid bootstrap-grid react-bootstrap

could some let me know what is the preferred way to do the responsive into react?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Just use plain JS, that's the beauty of React. I personally do this:

```
class Responsive extends Component {
  state = { isMobile: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    // use css media quries
    this.isMobile = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");

    // test on first run
    this.handleIsMobile({ matches: this.isMobile.matches });

    // listen to changes after first run
    this.isMobile.addListener(this.handleIsMobile);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // stop listening when unmounted
    this.isMobile.removeListener(this.handleIsMobile);
  }

  handleIsMobile = ({ matches }) => this.setState({ isMobile: matches });

  render() {
    if (this.state.isMobile) return <div>MOBILE</div>;

    return <div>DESKTOP</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First refer this, [Bootstrap webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)

This is one way of using bootstrap in reactjs projects.

The advantage of this is that u get access to latest bootstrap css.

The disadvantage of using this is its complicated to use jquery plugins in reactjs. Hovewr if you are only interested in css, then its perfect.

Using this u can directly use bootstrap classes from documentation and get more control.
Just use `className` instead of `class`

If u want simple setup , then u can use reactstrap [link](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Other frameworks include react-bootstrap [link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)